# error in cakephp while making friendship system in my friend controller

Tags: php

while making a friendship system in cakephp, i got error something like this in my friend controller---->

syntax error, unexpected ';'

pls someone sort out this problem....
here is my friendship controller  code:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
/**
 * Posts Controller
 *
 * @property Post $Post
 * @property PaginatorComponent $Paginator
 */
class FriendsController extends AppController 
{

/**
 * Components
 *
 * @var array
 */
    var $layout=null;
    public $components = array('Paginator');
    function index()
    {


    }

 function friendlist($user_id)
         {
                    $session_user_id = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');
                    if($user_id == $session_user_id )
                    {
                        $user_to = $session_user_id ;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $user_to = $user_id;
                    }
                    $this->Friend->find('all',array('Friend.user_to'=>$user_to,'Friend.status'=>'Accepted');
         }

function add_friend ( $id )
{
    if(!empty($this->data))
    {
        $this->Friend->Create();
        if($this->Friend->save($this->data))
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Friendship Requested');
            $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'login'));
        }
    }
if(empty($this->data))
    {
        $this->set('friends', $this->Friend->find('all',array('Friend.id'=>$id));
    }
}


    function accept_friendship ( $id )
             {
            $this->Friend->id = $id;
            $current_status = $this->Friend->field('status');

            if($current_status=='Requested') {
                $this->Application->saveField('status', 'Accepted');
            }

            $this->Session->setFlash('Friendship Accepted');
            $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'friends','action'=>'index'));
        }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error. In line 36 and in line 52. You forget to add closing bracket

Change code from

```
$this->Friend->find('all',array('Friend.user_to'=>$user_to,'Friend.status'=>'Accepted');
```

to

```
$this->Friend->find('all',array('Friend.user_to'=>$user_to,'Friend.status'=>'Accepted'));
```

from

```
$this->set('friends', $this->Friend->find('all',array('Friend.id'=>$id));
```

to

```
$this->set('friends', $this->Friend->find('all',array('Friend.id'=>$id)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply there is the problem with syntax,where you forget to close brackets in find and set syntax

Add following code and try :

```
$this->Friend->find('all',array('Friend.user_to'=>$user_to,'Friend.status'=>'Accepted'));
```

and

```
$this->set('friends', $this->Friend->find('all',array('Friend.id'=>$id)));
```

And my suggestion to you that please use some nice one editor which helps you with syntax errors, like I am using netbeans and its best.

Comment: if that works for you please can you upvote answer and accept it ?